# Why these links don't change the height of my div?

Tags: html, css

The links don't change the "holder" height at all, really I don't know what is wrong

**HTML:**

```
<div id="holder">
<a class="button" href="#"><span>home</span></a>
<a class="button" href="#"><span>example</span></a>
<a class="button" href="#"><span>another examp.</span></a>
<a class="button" href="#"><span>hello</span></a>
<a class="button" href="#"><span>abc</span></a>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
*{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
#holder{
width:100%;
background: #000;
border: 1px solid red;
}
.button {
    color: #444;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 24px;
    margin-right: 6px;
    padding-right: 18px;
}
.button span {
    display: block;
    line-height: 14px;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 18px;
}
.button:hover {
    background: #333 url('./images/bg_button_a.jpg') no-repeat scroll top right;
    outline: none;
}

.button:hover span {
    background: #333 url('./images/bg_button_span.jpg') no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Why do you open a `span` and then close a `li` ?

Comment: oops, because I tried with everything, (but I can assure you that is not the problem)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Elements do not automatically expand to contain floated descendents.

Adding [`overflow: hidden`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/overflow) is one type of *clearfix* and so long as you don't mind elements being clipped at the element's bounding box, the easiest.

```
#holder {
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

[Further Reading](http://www.positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html).

Comment: +1 This needs more promotion over the overabundant `<div style="clear: left;"></div>`.

Answer (score 2):

It's because they are float:left, such subelements don't expand the dimensions of their parent.
Easiest way to counteract this is to add

```
 <div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

at the end of the children. E.g:

```
<div id="holder">
    <a class="button" href="#"><span>home</span></a>
    <a class="button" href="#"><span>example</span></a>
    <a class="button" href="#"><span>another examp.</span></a>
    <a class="button" href="#"><span>hello</span></a>
    <a class="button" href="#"><span>abc</span></a>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Opening span but closing li could cause some trouble.

```
<a class="button" href="#"><span>hello</li></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Floated elements to not extend the height of their container. Essentially, they are all bound to the top of the container (which visually is not the case).

Use a div with `clear:left` at the bottom of the container to expand it to contain the floated elements.

Answer (score 0):

Floated elements do not count towards the height of their parent.
Setting `overflow: hidden;` on `#holder` is a neat trick to rectify that.